# How to integrate react (with hooks) in small parts of an existing site?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was following [this well known tutorial](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html) about adding react to a website. I was trying to replace my actual login div which contains many elements like form, buttons, spans, etc. However when I was setting up a controlled input component via React.useState, this leaded to the error reported in title.

I'll try to reproduce the problem with this simple snippet.

```js
var LoginBox = function LoginBox(props) {
  var rusername = React.useState('');
  var username = rusername[0];
  var setUsername = rusername[1];
  var rpassword = React.useState('');
  var password = rpassword[0];
  var setPassword = rpassword[1];
  var style = { width: 180 };
  var onLogin = function onLogin() {
    console.log('login');
  };
  var onLogout = function onLogout() {
    console.log('logout');
  };
  return React.createElement('div', null, 'loginbox');
  };
var domContainer = document.querySelector('#loginBoxContainer');
ReactDOM.render(LoginBox(), domContainer);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>other html</div>
<div id="loginBoxContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Why is this error raised?
What can I do to add react to parts of my website without having to rewrite all of it in react?

Comment: `ReactDOM.render(e(LikeButton), domContainer);` not `ReactDOM.render(LoginBox(), domContainer);` Or try jsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `LoginBox()` you need to use `React.createElement(LoginBox)`

```js
var LoginBox = function LoginBox(props) {
  var rusername = React.useState('');
  var username = rusername[0];
  var setUsername = rusername[1];
  var rpassword = React.useState('');
  var password = rpassword[0];
  var setPassword = rpassword[1];
  var style = { width: 180 };
  var onLogin = function onLogin() {
    console.log('login');
  };
  var onLogout = function onLogout() {
    console.log('logout');
  };
  return React.createElement('div', null, 'loginbox');
  };
var domContainer = document.querySelector('#loginBoxContainer');
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(LoginBox), domContainer);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>other html</div>
<div id="loginBoxContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
var LoginBox = function LoginBox(props) {
  var [username, setUsername] = React.useState("");
  var [password, setPassword] = React.useState("");

  return React.createElement("div", null, "loginbox");
};

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(LoginBox, null),
    document.getElementById('loginBoxContainer')
  );
});
```

live demo here: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GNPVHJEXE03P